# How to configure git status message to not reference git push?

Tags: git

git status reports:

> ```
> # On branch master 
> # Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit. 
> # (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
> ```

Is there a configuration file or some other way to override that message?
Especially removing the "git push" reference?
I don't want people to use "git push" but rather to use a different tool.

Answer (score 2):

See if this works:

```
git config advice.statusHints false
```

Addressing your comment as to whether some messages can be printed but not others:

No. Sorry, but this behavior is hard-coded into git. The same variable (`advice_status_hints`) is used to determine whether each message is printed. The only way to do this with git would be to create your own fork of git, edit the code, and build from source.
However, there is a hacked-together solution that involves redefining git to be a function in `.bashrc`:

```
git() {
    if [[ $1 == "status" ]];
    then
        command git "$@" | sed '/# (use "git push" to publish your local commits)/d'
    else
        command git "$@";
    fi;
}
```

It's not elegant, but it works by deleting the matching line if the command is `git status`.

Comment: Right direction.  But I'd like the users to still get other  messages.   For example when there is modified files but nothing added, status gives a useful hint of '(use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")'

Comment: @TomO This isn't possible using git, but there is a bash solution (see my post).